# How do I select an element in jQuery and execute an anonymous function without binding it to an event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Let's say I have a div with two anchors:

```
<div id="#dialog">
    <a href="#" class="ok">Delete</a>
    <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

In order to make the `<a>` anchors work, I'm using the following two calls:

```
$('#dialog a.ok').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ ... });
    $(this).closest('#dialog').dialog('close');
});

 $('#dialog a.cancel').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

I'd like to be able to combine it to something like this instead:

```
$('#dialog').execute(function() {
    var dialog = $(this);

    dialog.find('a.ok').click(function() {
        $.ajax({ ... });
        dialog.dialog('close');
    });

    dialog.find('a.cancel').click(function() {
        dialog.dialog('close');
    });
});
```

The fake `exeucte()` function will execute the anonymous function immediately, without binding it to a DOM event. I'd like to use this pattern in order to group related functions together (in this case, a dialog has two buttons that are very closely related to each other).

**My question is twofold:**

1. What is the actual jQuery call I should be using here?
2. Is this the best way of grouping related functions together?

Comment: Nice question! I don't know if this is the *best* way, but `.each(function(){ ... })` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any special jQuery stuff for this, just write a function and give it `$('#dialog')` as an argument:

```
function do_stuff(dialog) {
    dialog.find('a.ok').click(function() {
        $.ajax({ ... });
        dialog.dialog('close');
    });

    dialog.find('a.cancel').click(function() {
        dialog.dialog('close');
    });
}

do_stuff($('#dialog'));
```

Or, if you really have a thing for anonymous functions, you could use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('#dialog').each(function() {
    var dialog = $(this);

    dialog.find('a.ok').click(function() {
        $.ajax({ ... });
        dialog.dialog('close');
    });

    dialog.find('a.cancel').click(function() {
        dialog.dialog('close');
    });
});
```

but using `each` with a selector that can only match a single element looks funny. You could also define your own self-executing function:

```
(function(dialog) {
    dialog.find('a.ok').click(function() {
        $.ajax({ ... });
        dialog.dialog('close');
    });

    dialog.find('a.cancel').click(function() {
        dialog.dialog('close');
    });
})($('#dialog'));
```

There is no best here, you use what fits your particular circumstances and local conventions.